# How can I stream audio from base64 chunks?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

This question is about javascript on the browser side.

I am receiving chunks with audio in base64 format. Every chunk is up to 750 kB. When I wait and merge chunks in one the audio file plays well.

Can I start to play audio without waiting for all chunks to load?

This code is downloading the whole audio and playing it (works properly):

```js
      let after = ''
      let hasNextPage = true;
      let base64 = ''
      while(hasNextPage){
       let chunk = await downloadChunk(fileId, after)
        base64 += chunk.base64
        after = chunk.after
        hasNextPage = chunk.hasNextPage
       // break
      }
      
      const audio = new Audio()        
      audio.src = base64 
      audio.play()
```

Comment: Sure, set the base64 content as the source for the Audio element, then when the `ended` event fires, update the content to the next chunk. You *may* encounter a slight skip in the playback, though. You may be able to overcome this depending on when the chunks are requested/received and what player you're using. More details are required on your exact implementation for any of us to be able to help you.

Comment: Provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Updated question with code. I got the error with uncommented `break` when I try to play 1 chunk:  
```Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.```